# Unable to play video on mouseover in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have loaded videos into a search results page. On mouseenter I want to load a preview of the video into a separate div. The video will then start playing in the div.

```
$(".videoSearchResults video").mouseenter(function () {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    $(container).attr("class", "videoOverlay");
    $(container).css({
        "position": "relative",
        "padding": "5%",
        "height": "130px",
        "background-color": "rgb(211, 209, 209)",
    });
    var sources = $(this).html();
    var clip = "<video autoplay='autoplay' style='max-width: 100%; height: 120px;'>" + sources + "</video>";
    var output = clip;
    $(container).append(output);
    $(this).parent().append(container);
    $(clip).get(0).play();
```

The solution works in Firefox, but the videos fail to play in Chrome. Is there a solution to make this work in Chrome?

Comment: Do you have an error in Chrome console ?

Comment: There were no errors in the console. The problem turned out to be i was making too many requests to the server and therefore the limit for the number of available sockets was reached.

Answer (score 1):

You must have `clip` as jQuery object all the time otherwise you would create a new object with the same code in the last line (`$(clip).get(0).play();`)

This should work:

```
var clip = $("<video autoplay='autoplay' style='max-width: 100%; height: 120px;'>" + sources + "</video>");
var output = clip;
$(container).append(output);
$(this).parent().append(container);
clip.get(0).play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with videos in chrome.

Try adding ID to your video HTML string before you include append it to the markup and then

```
var vid = document.getElementById('clip');
clip.play()
```